# Bevel does not work correctly on one edge only

Tags: edit-mode

Back to my shed (which I am modelling on an existing shed).
I am trying to create faces for the timber framing on the corners of my shed using the Bevel 'tool' (select edges with segments set to 2 and shape set to 1). It works correctly on 3 of the 4 corners but on the fourth corner it goes crazy. I have found that I have somehow got two edges on this corner (I can select an edge, press X and select dissolve edges and an edge remains) but even selecting one and removing it (dissolve) bevel still won't operate correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have duplicate vertices in your mesh, `A` to select all, then `M` > _Merge_ > _By Distance_. But do it before you try to bevel the edge. By the way, do you have a new profile pic? :)

Comment: How easy was that. Thanks heaps Gordon.  Now I wonder how I ended up with duplicate vertices. I could see I had (what appeared to be) duplicate edges but obviously that was because of duplicate vertices. Tricky. Thanks again.    Can I sneak in another question please? I would like to add short 'legs' at the bottom of each corner. How can I do that without adding extra meshes (one for each 'leg')? Easier to add the extra meshes?